# Writing proof (disproof) prime number formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Please prove or disprove: If $n \in ℤ^{+}$, then $n^{2} + n + 41$ is prime.

I know that the above statement is not true because if you plug in 41 for $n$, the result is not a prime number. How can I write a formal proof (or disproof) showing that this is a false statement?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the statement is false, so you must show with a counterexample.

Comment: You are already done. As DonQuixote said, you merely need to give a counterexample, which you have already done by letting $n=41$.

Comment: You have done it. Maybe you should indicate how you know that the number is not prime when $n=41$. Or maybe it is so obvious that it is not worth doing. By the way, the number is also composite at $n=40$, and is prime for $n=1$ to $39$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no polynomial with integer coefficients that is able to take only prime values over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$.

The reason is simple: if $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $a-b$ is a divisor of $p(a)-p(b)$ for every $a\neq b$ (that obviously holds for monomials, hence it holds for polynomials, too). Moreover, a polynomial cannot take the same value in more points than its degree. Assuming that $p(1)$ is some prime $q$, then $q$ divides $p(kq+1)-p(1)$, hence $p(kq+1)$, for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. If $n$ is the degree of $p(x)$, it follows that at least a number among $p(q+1),p(2q+1),\ldots,p((2n+1)q+1)$ *cannot* be a prime.

Answer (score 0):

["An Introduction To The Theory Of Numbers" by Hardy](http://www.amazon.co.uk/An-Introduction-Theory-Numbers-Hardy/dp/0199219869) (or http://matematica.cubaeduca.cu/medias/pdf/842.pdf), Theorem 21, page 18.

> THEOREM 21. No polynomial $f(n)$ with integral coefficients, not a
>   constant, can be prime for all $n$, or for all sufficiently large $n$.