# For every positive integer $n$, $n^2 + n +19$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove that for every positive integer $n, n^2 + n +19$ is prime.

I tried to disapprove it saying that is is not prime.

If it's not prime, then $n^2 + n +19$ has to have at least two factors which are greater than $1$. I'm stuck here.

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: If $n=19$, then $19\mid n^2+n+19 > 19$, so $n^2+n+19$ is composite if $n=19$.

Comment: It's not a prime for $n=1$

Comment: No polynomial with integer coefficients produces only primes.

Comment: Consider trying to prove that the all of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta Function have real part equal to one half. This will help you with your understanding of the distribution of prime numbers.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Nooooooo, the correct theorem says that if for every positive integer $n$, $n^2 + n + 19$ is prime, then Santa exists.

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's very easy. Imitate the first commenter's idea! :)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal oh lol of course.

Comment: I think you are trying to find $n\in \Bbb N$ for which $n^2+n+19$ is prime. Because, as @user236182, pointed out, it not true for a lot of positive integers.

Comment: If you expect something in the similar form, Euler found out that $n^2 + n + 41$ is prime for any $0 \leq n \leq 40$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try some values:

$n=1$
$$1^2+1+19=21=3*7$$

$n=2$
$$2^2+2+19=25=5*5$$

$n=5$
$$5^2+5+19=49=7*7$$

Even one counter example was enough to prove that the statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't forget to mention some other condition that makes this a much more difficult problem, such as for example that $n \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$?

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, and since $19$ also satisfies that congruence, $n^2 + n + 19$ is a multiple of $3$.

Spend a few minutes looking at [this page from FactorDB.com](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=n%5E2%20%2B%20n%20%2B%2019&use=n&n=1&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&FF=on&PRP=on&CF=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=200&format=1&sent=Show).

Answer (score 1):

I answered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452702/writing-proof-disproof-prime-number-formula/1452723#1452723) once.

["An Introduction To The Theory Of Numbers" by Hardy](http://matematica.cubaeduca.cu/medias/pdf/842.pdf), Theorem 21, page 18.

> THEOREM 21. No polynomial $f(n)$ with integral coefficients, not a
>   constant, can be prime for all $n$, or for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

This proposition is not true, and more generally it is not true if 19 is replaced by *any* positive integer $k$.  For $k>1$ we can obtain a counterexample by putting $n=k-1$ so that:
$$n^2 + n + k = (k-1)^2+(k-1)+k= (k^2-2k+1)+(k-1)+k=k^2$$
For $k=1$ a counterexample is $n=4$ implying $n^2+n+1 = 21 = 3*7$.