# Arithmetic sequence where every term is prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I conjecture that there does not exist an arithmetic sequence where every number is prime. Put another way, the set
$$S_{a,b} = \{a + \delta b \ \vert \delta \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
Where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$

contains *some* composite number.

I have no idea how to approach such a question. Googling let me to theorems about densities of primes in arithmetic sequences (Green-Tao and the like), but nothing that answers this elementary question.

Comment: What happens if $\delta=a$?

Comment: @quasi That takes care of $a≠1$ but if $a=1$ it's not always sufficient. Fortunately it's not hard to see that $b\delta+1$ contains arbitrarily large multiples of $b+1$.

Comment: If $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then there are infinitely many $d\in \Bbb N$ such that $a+bd$ is prime. This is called Dirichlet's Theorem. It is not easy or elementary.

Comment: Would 3-5-7 or 7-37-67 be a case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As quasi points out in a comment, when $\delta=a$ the element is $a(b+1)$ which is composite unless possibly $a=1$.

More generally just take $\delta = kb+k+a$ for any positive $k$.  Then the element is $$kb^2 +(k+a)b + a = (kb+a)(b+1)$$ which is composite.

Comment: This post brought to you by the P.D.Q. Bernoulli Institute of Lower Mathematics.

Comment: Much appreciated :) I came up with the $a(b + 1)$ right after posting the question, but didn't notice the corner case of $a = 1$.

Comment: Is this an "insight" proof, is there a method to come up with this?

Comment: Quasi's observation takes care of $a≠1$. For $a=1$ I just looked at an example, picking $4b+1$ arbitrarily. Because $\gcd(4,5)=1$ this was obviously going to hit a multiple of 5 every 5 terms.  The generalization was immediate: $1+\delta b$ contains infinitely many multiples of $b+1$.

Comment: @siddharth I wrote up my thought process in more detail: https://blog.plover.com/math/arithmetic-sequences.html

Comment: Thank you for writing that down!

Answer (score 4):

I answered similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452702/writing-proof-disproof-prime-number-formula/1452723#1452723) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702267/for-every-positive-integer-n-n2-n-19-is-prime/1702395#1702395).

["An Introduction To The Theory Of Numbers" by Hardy](http://matematica.cubaeduca.cu/medias/pdf/842.pdf), Theorem 21, page 18.

> THEOREM 21. No polynomial $f(n)$ with integral coefficients, not a
>   constant, can be prime for all $n$, or for all sufficiently large $n$.

In this case $f(\delta)=a+\delta b$. It's a more powerful result, but the proof is very simple, [as you will see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922009/prove-that-there-is-no-polynomial-px-a-n-xn-a-n-1-xn-1-ldots-a/1922064#1922064).

Comment: $f(nr+c)\equiv f(c) \bmod r$, taking $r=f(c)$ we get that $f(nf(c)+c)$ is divisible by $f(c)$ for all $n\in \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is quasi-immediate: $a+ab$ is composite.

---

**Update:**

There is a special case which invalidates the claim: $a=1$.

Using MJD's method, $a+(a+b+1)b=(a+b)(b+1)$ is always composite.

Comment: "quasi-immediate" is funny! I didn't get it until just now.

Comment: @MJD: though you found a harder version of it.

Comment: I meant your pun: it was in fact "quasi-immediate" because quasi had immediately posted [a comment pointing it out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741007/arithmetic-sequence-where-every-term-is-prime/2741040?noredirect=1#comment5655974_2741007).

Comment: @MJD: unintentional, I didn't get it either ! :)

Answer (score 1):

We can in fact prove that the sequence contains infinitely many multiples of every number $n$ that is relatively prime to $b$. (Like $n = b + 1$ in MJD's answer.)

Pick any number $n$ such that $\gcd(b, n) = 1$. This [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity&oldid=835657181) there exist integers $x, y$ such that $nx - by = 1$. (The nice thing about $n=b+1$ is that we can write down $x$ and $y$ explicitly, as $x=y=1$.)

Now take $\delta = nk + ay$ for any $k$.

Then, $a + \delta b = a + (nk + ay)b = a + nkb + a(nx - 1) = n(kb + ax)$ which is a multiple of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your information:

There is an arithmetic progression which has ten prime terms and its first term is 199 and common difference is 210:

$199, 409, 829,1039,1249, 1459, 1669,1879, 2089$

Also due to Sierpinski theorem the longest Arithmetic progression with prime numbers has 13 terms, first number is $4943$ and the common difference  is $60060$.

There is also a theorem that claims there is infinitely many Arithmetic progressions with 13 numbers and common difference  $30030$ with all numbers prime, but there has not been found even one yet!

Comment: > "Also due to Sierpinski theorem the longest Arithmetic progression with prime numbers has 13 terms"

But doesn't the Green-Tao theorem tell us that we can get arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions consisting entirely of prime numbers?

Comment: There is an arithmetric progression of length 26 known:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression#Largest_known_primes_in_AP

Comment: And 14933623 + 30030·n is prime for 13 terms (n=0..12).
http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm#minimal